# What is the package name for the default Samsung Gallery App?

Tags: samsung

Deleted it while debloating my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra. I am unable to install it via the Samsung store. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The default package name of the Samsung Gallery app (at least on my Samsung device here) is

```
com.sec.android.gallery3d
```

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.gallery3d

Comment: Same on my Samsung Galaxy A7